# Soft Recovery collar too tight?

Tags: cats, collar

I bought my cat, Rhea, a soft recovery collar to replace her cone. It looks like a plushy donut around her neck.

I think it's the right size but I'm always paranoid it's too tight. She ate twice with it and drank water. She also hasn't tried to take it off. I can fit 1-2 fingers snuggly around her neck (before she nips at me in annoyance).

Would she show signs if it was too tight?

Answer (score 4):

If the cat:

- shows no sign of distress (not even trying to get it off);
- eats and drinks normally;
- and you checked with your fingers that there’s enough room between collar and her neck;

clearly everything is fine. In fact, she seems unusually calm considering that most cats find any kind of cone a major nuisance.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe her lack of anxiety was making me nervous. She looks much more comfortable now than when she had the e-cone.